# Composer Bot receiving intent from Luis, executing "Unknown Intent" instead of matching "Intent Recognized"

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer, azure-language-understanding

I have a bot built in Bot Framework Composer, and I haven't had any issues with adding intents within composer matched to a trigger before.

When I added a new trigger called "SearchWiki" and add utterances, then build the bot, when I test the new trigger, the luis trace returns with "topIntent": "SearchWiki", but the bot executes the actions found in the "Unknown Intent" trigger. This only happens with new intents, as the onther intents I have built still work fine. The only change I can think of that might have affected this is below (note: reverting below changes did not solve the issue)

I recently changed the bot app settings to control the luis app more directly as follows:

FROM:

```
"environment": "composer",
```

TO:

```
"<BOT_NAME>_en_us_lu": {
      "appId": "<APP_ID>"
    },
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while I don't have an exact reason for this, this problem was solved after deleting the following folders from the repository:
./obj/
./bin/
./generated/

I assume that it most likely had to do with the "generated" folder, but if I run into the exact reason I'll document it here for posterity.